# Adding Numeric Values through Javascript & PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Basically I am trying to multiply values together.

I have a ul below that is echo'ing out a numeric value,:

```
<ul class="TCE">
<li><span>Average drink cost</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo the_field('average_drink_price'); ?></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure per night</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night'); ?></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure for the year</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- JAVA BIT --></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure for 3 years</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; <!-- JAVA BIT --></li>
</ul>
```

I want the third li to get the value of the second li and then multiply that value by exactly 28.

I then want the fourth li to get the value of the third li and multiply that by 3.

So it goes a little like this:

li-2 x 28 = li-3
li-3 x 3 = li-4

If that makes sense? The value's for li1 and li2 will be generated via that PHP field, any help on this as I have no idea where to start?

Updated PHP testing:

```
<?php
var_dump(the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night')); 
$li2 = the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night');
$li3 = ($li2 * 28) * 2.1;
$li4 = $li3 * 3;
?>

<ul class="TCE">
<li><span>Average drink cost</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo the_field('average_drink_price'); ?></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure per night</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $li2; ?></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure for the year</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $li3;?><!-- JAVA BIT --></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure for 3 years</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $li4;?><!-- JAVA BIT --></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is `the_field`? Why can't you just echo the results of that calculation since you already have the values.... I am confused.....

Comment: if you have a variable 'var' you can surely use that on next line. var*28.

Comment: is the field variable? Shouldnt it be $the_field.

Comment: @optimist It is probably a method he imported, but there is no way to know from the information given.

Comment: Ignore the php mark up as that is correct and is done through a wordpress plugin, but that is not really necessary to know. 

What would be echo'd there instead would be a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY

```
<?php 
$li2 = 1;
if(is_numeric(trim(the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night'))))
 $li2 = trim(the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night'));
$li3 = $li2 * 28;
$li4 = $li3 * 3;

?>

<ul class="TCE">
<li><span>Average drink cost</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo   the_field('average_drink_price'); ?></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure per night</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $li2; ?></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure for the year</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php  echo $li3;?><!-- JAVA BIT --></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure for 3 years</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; <!-- JAVA BIT --></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: unfortunately that does not work, all the values are being returned currently as 0, I think that's because it is not getting the value from $li2 though - anymore ideas?

Comment: what `the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night');` function is returning

Comment: it works when I put an actual numeric value in, but I wan't to take the value from the custom field.

Comment: is `the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night');` an function or Array if function what value it is returning and if array then it should be like `$the_field['average_drinks_spenditure_per_night'];`

Comment: it displays the value fine, so the function is fine and it returns the value as: the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night'); - but that php calculation is not recognising the value.

It just displays it above, see live link at: http://universitycompare.com/university-guide/aberdeen-university/ and then click 'Total Cost of Education' tab

Comment: unless I have done something wrong it retuned a value as 'Array' - Have I missed something? - Apologies if I have by the way.

Comment: try `var_dump(the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night'));` this will give you better idea

Comment: are you saying var_dump function outputting 15NULL ? seems unlikely

Comment: yes unless it's just NULL? - sorry PHP isn't my strong point.

I have updated my question with how my php structure is currently looking.

Comment: finally worked out by tweaking your code EVER so slightly! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?  Where does the JavaScript come in?

```
<?php
    $perNight = the_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night');
    $perYear = $perNight * 365;
    $per3Years = $perYear * 3;
?>    

<ul class="TCE">
    <li><span>Average drink cost</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo the_field('average_drink_price'); ?></li>
    <li><span>Average drinks spenditure per night</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $perNight; ?></li>
    <li><span>Average drinks spenditure for the year</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $perYear; ?></li>
    <li><span>Average drinks spenditure for 3 years</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $per3Years; ?></li>
</ul>
```